# Modifying React Data Table Extension Component

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to modify the react data table extension component with the below functionalities but I'm stuck and unable to modify it.

1. Change auto filter to event based filter set to button onClick
2. Change default search icon to bootstrap button
3. Use the export and print button (currently set the ... Data to the data-table-extension as per documentation but it is only displays the data in the data table but I'm unable to use print and export functionality).

I'm currently using react 18

I have tried to put data in the react data table component, when I do so the print and export functionality works perfectly fine but no data gets display in the data table.

My code is as under:

```
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component"; 

 import { tableCustomStyles } from "../../utils/CommonFunctions"; 

 import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions"; 


export default function UsersPage() {

  const dataTableColumns = [

     { 

       name: "#", 

       selector: (row, index) => `${index + 1}`, 

       sortable: false, 

       width: "50px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "Last Name", 

       selector: (row) => row.lastName, 

       sortable: true, 

       width: "150px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "First Name", 

       selector: (row) => row.firstName, 

       sortable: true, 

       width: "150px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "Role(s)", 

       selector: (row) => row?.roles?.map((role) => role?.name).join(", "), 

       sortable: true, 

       width: "230px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "Department(s)", 

       selector: (row) => 

         row?.departments?.map((department) => department?.name).join(", "), 

       sortable: true, 

       width: "230px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "Location(s)", 

       selector: (row) => 

         row?.locations?.map((location) => location?.name).join(", "), 

       sortable: true, 

       width: "230px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "Status", 

       selector: (row) => row?.status, 

       sortable: true, 

       width: "100px", 

     }, 

     { 

       name: "Option(s)", 

       cell: (row) => ( 

         <> 

           <Dropdown> 

             <Dropdown.Toggle variant='link' id='dropdown-basic'> 

               <VerticalDots style={{ height: 20 }} /> 

             </Dropdown.Toggle> 

  

             <Dropdown.Menu> 

               <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleViewFullProfile(row)}> 

                 View Full Profile 

               </Dropdown.Item> 

               <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleResetPassword(row)}> 

                 Reset Password 

               </Dropdown.Item> 

               <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleUserStatus(row)}> 

                 {row.status === "Active" ? "Deactivate" : "Activate"} User 

               </Dropdown.Item> 

               <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleOptionClick(row)}> 

                 Other Option 

               </Dropdown.Item> 

             </Dropdown.Menu> 

           </Dropdown> 

         </> 

       ), 

       ignoreRowClick: true, 

       allowOverflow: true, 

       button: true, 

       sortable: false, 

       width: "100px", 

     }, 

   ]; 

   const tableData = { 

     columns: dataTableColumns, 

     data: users, 




 
return (
<div>
          <a 

             className='btn btn-primary' 

             to='/admin/administer/new-user' 

             onClick={handleNavigation} 

           > 

             + Add User 

           </a> 

           <DataTableExtensions 

             {...tableData} 

             export={true} 

             print={true} 

             extensions={extensions} 

           > 

             <DataTable 

               // columns={dataTableColumns} 

               // data={users} 

               noHeader 

               defaultSortField='lastName' 

               defaultSortAsc={false} 

               customStyles={tableCustomStyles} 

               pagination 

               responsive='true' 

               highlightOnHover 

             /> 

           </DataTableExtensions> 

         </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve my concerns... And I learned that currently react-data-table-component and extension don't give much flexibility when it comes to updating the component to your specific requirements. And the last update of the component was one year old, with total downloads within 2-2.5k

So I used my custom input and search button and filtered the data being received through back end and to fix the issues of export and print I gave data as string in the selector instead of (row) => row.name method

Also one more challenge that I was facing was that data table was displaying conent that was growing outside the container giving a horizontal scroll option which was not required so I used wrap property for columns with more text and gave fixed width to columns with less text to resolve this issue.

My updated Code is as under:

```
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import {
  searchFunctionality,
  tableCustomStyles,
} from "../../utils/CommonFunctions";
import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions";
import "react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css";

export default function RolesData() {
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);
  const [filteredValue, setFilteredValue] = useState("");
  const [finalFilteredValue, setFinalFilteredValue] = useState("");
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const filteredData = searchFunctionality(
      roles,
      dataTableColumns,
      finalFilteredValue
    );
    setFilteredData(filteredData);
  }, [roles, finalFilteredValue]);

  const callGetRolesApi = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await getRoles();
      const { message, data, status } = res;

      console.log(res);
      if (status == clientSideStatus.success) {
        data.forEach((user, index) => {
          user.serial = index + 1;
          user.refinedRoles = user?.roles?.map((role) => role?.name).join(", ");  });

        setRoles(data);
        setFilteredData(data);
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        toast.error(message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      toast.error(clientDefinedMessages.rolesError);
    }
  };

const dataTableColumns = [
    {
      name: "#",
      selector: "serial",
      sortable: false,
      width: "50px",
    },
    {
      name: "Role Name",
      selector: "name",
      sortable: true,
      // width: "140px",
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Type of Role",
      selector: "roleTypeName",
      sortable: true,
      // width: "140px",
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Status",
      selector: "status",
      sortable: true,
      width: "140px",
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Member(s)",
      selector: "usersCount",
      style: { "text-decoration": "link", color: "blue" },
      sortable: false,
      // width: "140px",
      wrap: true,
      ignoreRowClick: true,
      allowOverflow: true,
      button: true,
      width: "150px",
      cell: (row) => (
        <>
          <button
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-link '
            onClick={() => handleMembersCountNavigation(row)}
          >
            {row.usersCount}
          </button>
        </>
      ),
    },
    {
      name: "Option(s)",
      cell: (row) => (
        <>
          <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle
              variant='fade-primary'
              id={`dropdown-${row?.role?.id}`}
              className='d-flex'
            >
              <VerticalDots style={{ height: 20 }} />
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Item
                onClick={() => handleViewDetailsNavigation(row?.id)}
              >
                View Details
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
        </>
      ),
      sortable: false,
      // width: "140px",
      wrap: true,
      ignoreRowClick: true,
      allowOverflow: true,
      button: true,
      width: "150px",
    },
  ];

  const tableData = {
    columns: dataTableColumns,
    data: filteredData,
  };

return (
    <>
      {!roles ? (
        <div className='d-flex justify-content-center p-3'>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div
          className='d-flex align-intems-center flex-wrap col-md-6 col-lg-12'
          style={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "center" }}
        >
          <a
            className='btn btn-primary d-flex align-items-center'
            to='/admin/administer/new-user'
            onClick={handleNavigation}
          >
            + Add User
          </a>
          <div
            className='input-group ms-auto'
            style={{ width: 340, display: "inline-flex" }}
          >
            <input
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              placeholder='Search Users'
              value={filteredValue}
              aria-describedby='button-addon2'
              onChange={(event) => setFilteredValue(event.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              className='btn btn-outline-primary'
              type='button'
              id='button-addon2'
              onClick={() => setFinalFilteredValue(filteredValue)}
            >
              Go
            </button>
            <button
              type='button'
              className='btn btn-outline-primary'
              aria-label='Clear'
              onClick={() => {
                setFilteredValue("");
                setFinalFilteredValue("");
              }}
            >
              Clear
            </button>
          </div>

          <DataTableExtensions {...tableData} filter={false}>
            <DataTable
              columns={dataTableColumns}
              data={roles}
              noHeader
              // defaultSortField='lastName'
              defaultSortAsc={false}
              customStyles={tableCustomStyles}
              pagination
              highlightOnHover
            />
          </DataTableExtensions>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

The common functions created for the styling and filtering data are as under:

`````
export const tableCustomStyles = {
  headCells: {
    style: {
      fontSize: "14px",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      paddingLeft: "8px",
      justifyContent: "left",
      color: "#1e78fd",
    },
  },
  cells: {
    style: {
      fontSize: "14px",
      paddingLeft: "8px",
      justifyContent: "left",
      whiteSpace: "normal",
    },
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    marginBottom: "20px",
    // Add any other custom styles you need
  },
  filterInput: {
    marginRight: "10px",
    // Add any other custom styles for the filter input
  },
};

export const searchFunctionality = (data, dataTableColumns, filteredValue) => {
  let data1 = data?.filter((dat) => {
    if (filteredValue !== "") {
      for (let i = 0; i < dataTableColumns.length; i++) {
        if (dataTableColumns[i]?.selector) {
          if (
            dat[dataTableColumns[i]?.selector]
              ?.toString()
              ?.toLowerCase()
              ?.includes(filteredValue?.toLowerCase())
          )
            return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  data1?.forEach((user, index) => {
    user.serial = index + 1;
  });
  return data1;
};
````[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1JNH.png
`````

Comment: So the latest on the above is that, react data table component is really a good library to use. But React Data Table Extension component is currently out of date

Comment: I had to stop using react-data-table-extension-component in my application and now i'm using custom export to csv and custom print function

Comment: last but not the least, custom filter functionality. The custom functionalities gave life to my data tables and the UI/UX is the best now.

Comment: In fact-let me share the updated code.